# Parsing issue with ruby Mixlib::ShellOut in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, mixlib-shellout

I'm trying to extend an existing cookbook where we use Mixlib::ShellOut to collect a fair amount of information about an Oracle install. Mostly it just works.

I'm trying to add a node attribute for where TFA is running - because that can vary depending on version. From the server itself, a simple
`ps -ef | grep tfa | grep java | awk '{print $NF}'` gives me exactly what I need.

When I add that to the recipe as

```
tfa_home = ::Mixlib::ShellOut.new("ps -ef | grep tfa | grep java | awk '{print $NF}'")
tfa_home.run_command
node.normal['gbucs_oracledb']['orahome']['tfa_home'] = tfa_home.stdout.strip
```

The resulting output json seems to get a newline char as well as the string "$NF'":

```
"tfa_home": "/u01/app/19.0.0.0/grid/tfa/<hostname>/tfa_home\n$NF}'"
```

I've tried a couple variants of escaping the $NF, but no luck so far. Is there an obvious solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [String.gsub](https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String#gsub-instance_method) ?

```rb
tfa_home.stdout.strip.gsub(/\n\$NF}'/, '')
```

Comment: I ended up using `tfa_home.stdout.strip.gsub(/[\n\$NF}']/,'')`. Thank you so much - this was driving me crazy!

Comment: `/[\n\$NF}']/` - will find occurrences of each 1 symbol in the square brackets. I bet you don't want to replace _any_ N, F, } and ' with nothing.